# Switching a power BJT

Tags: bjt

Say Q2 is a power BJT like the [E13009](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MJE13009-D.PDF) and I want to control the BJT through a microcontroller for example an Arduino.

I thought of this circuit and wondered is it good enough for switching the power BJT. I didn't calculate the value of the resistors, they are just some common 1K and 10K resistors.

RL is my load and let say the load current is about 5A, Q1 is a general purpose NPN BJT, and SW1 represents the output from a microcontroller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5W4jk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Edited: The new schematic for a D44H11

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnf36H.png)</sup>

Comment: Is the switch supposed to represent a MCU output? And which one is the power transistor?

Comment: Use a MOSFET...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, the switch represents a MCU output, Q2 is the power transistor, I've edited the schematic to show it more clearly.

Comment: @MattYoung I know, but I wanted to learn ways to control a Power BJT from a MCU.

Comment: That BJT is totally unsuited for the 5 volt power and load so, if you were to pick a more suited transistor, maybe the learning process would be more sensible. Having said that, the process has begun for you and you should now be convinced that the BJT shown is unsuitable so, go find another as part of this process. If you are not convinced so far then you need to read what has been said again and again until you are.

Answer (score 4):

The gain is pretty miserable on that high voltage BJT- the Vce(sat) is rated at a forced beta of only 5, and if you look at Figure 6, that's not unreasonable considering how bad the 'typical' performance is even at room temperature. So with a 5A collector current you would need 1A base current, which is above the capability of the 2N3904. If you used two of the HV transistors your overall gain will only be 25, so you'd still need 200mA. Not very practical.

To look at it another way, you are giving the base of the output BJT about 4mA so it's good for switching about 5x that or 20mA.

Even a modest **logic level** MOSFET will do much, much better than this if you are really switching just 5V. The BJT may be somewhat more competitive if you are switching hundreds of volts.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your load is \$5\:\textrm{A}\$ and you are interested in learning about BJTs, you have two options for the final power stage BJT -- NPN or PNP. Sometimes, this is determined by things like "common cathode" or "common anode" arrangements in your load, so you are forced to choose one or the other. Sometimes, you get to pick how your load is tied so you can choose either.

For something in this current compliance range, you should be thinking about a TO-220 style package (or better.) A power BJT will drop some \$V_{CE}\$ across the switch, no matter what you do about it, and all of that times the current becomes power that has to be dissipated; plus whatever the base requires, as well. And at these currents, everything adds up.

A best case scenario is that you find a good quality power BJT that has decent gain at a collector current of \$5\:\textrm{A}\$, is multi-sourced, and is cheap and readily available. The [D44H and D45H series](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/D44H-D.PDF) qualifies. They are widely sourced, widely available, and cheap. About 40 cents [from Arrow](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/d45h11/stmicroelectronics) right now, in ones (as an example) for the PNP D45H11.

This PNP provides a guaranteed minimum \$h_{FE}=40\$ with \$I_C=4\:\textrm{A}\$. The actual gain of any given device is likely better. But I think you can plan on that figure here. The guaranteed worst case voltage drop limiting the load's voltage compliance is stated at \$I_C=8\:\textrm{A}\$ as \$V_{CE\left(sat\right)}=1\:\textrm{V}\$. But the typical value at your current is about 4 times better than that, or \$V_{CE\left(sat\right)}=250\:\textrm{mV}\$. The guaranteed worst case base-emitter drop at \$I_C=8\:\textrm{A}\$ is \$V_{BE\left(sat\right)}=1.5\:\textrm{V}\$, but the typical value is \$V_{BE\left(sat\right)}=1\:\textrm{V}\$.

A circuit for this might look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhi0kT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I first estimated the base current for \$Q_1\$ as \$I_{B_1}=\frac{5\:\textrm{A}}{\beta_1=40}=125\:\textrm{mA}\$. I set up a small current in \$R_1\$ to help pull the base up when \$Q_2\$ goes OFF. (About 2% of the base current.) \$V_{BE\left(sat\right)_1}=700 - 1500\:\textrm{mV}\$, so the base voltage may be \$3.5 - 4.3\:\textrm{V}\$. \$Q_3\$ is operated as a switch and I assumed \$V_{CE\left(sat\right)_2}=200-400\:\textrm{mV}\$ (and \$\beta_2=20\$.) This leaves \$R_3\$ having to drop \$3.2-4.1\:\textrm{V}\$ while also providing a minimum of \$125\:\textrm{mA}+2.5\:\textrm{mA}\approx 128\:\textrm{mA}\$. In the worst case, this would suggest \$R_3=25\:\Omega\$, but I decided to use \$R_3=27\:\Omega\$ as a nearby standard value. Given that I don't actually expect the absolute worst case of \$V_{BE\left(sat\right)_1}=1.5\:\textrm{V}\$, I think this is reasonable.

I computed the required base current for \$Q_2\$ as \$6.4\:\textrm{mA}\$. With a worst case \$V_{BE\left(sat\right)_2}=1\:\textrm{V}\$, that would imply \$R_2=625\:\Omega\$. But the standard value of \$R_2=560\:\Omega\$ guarantees a little more base current, which won't hurt any here.

Worst case power dissipations of interest are shown, as well. As you can see, \$R_3\$ will have to be a \$1\:\textrm{W}\$ resistor. The D45H11 probably won't actually dissipate \$5.1\:\textrm{W}\$, which is only in a highly unusual worst case situation. (Much more likely it will be closer to \$1-2\:\textrm{W}\$.)

Just be aware that the load may not get access to more than \$4.3-4.5\:\textrm{V}\$ and that it could see as little as \$4.0\:\textrm{V}\$ in the unusual worst case scenario.

---

A similar design process can be used to achieve this with the D44H11 NPN power BJT, as well.

---

These details are part of the reason that a MOSFET might be recommended in situations like this. They are more expensive and perhaps less widely sourced, but \$R_3\$ also isn't cheap and it takes up space. So you have to make decisions in your own situation about what works for you.

For me as a hobbyist? I have bucket loads of nearly free BJTs -- less than a half cent apiece for small signal and typically less than 10 cents each for TO-220. (I shop around.) So I usually use those, as well as giving them out to others by the hand-full. Stocking up on MOSFETs sets back my budget way too much for that freedom. So I use discrete MOSFETs somewhat sparingly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! And sorry for the late reply, I was busy dealing with my assignments.
I could not find cheap components here, maybe I did the shopping wrong?
I've edited my post to include another schematic, same circuit, but different resistors' values and changed the power BJT to be D44H11, will that work?

Comment: @JohnHJ What parts do you have that are "cheap" for power usage? The D44H and D45H still provide pretty good beta at the currents you want and they are about 12 cents in 1's at Arrow. (I see where you took account of my calcs with your new schematic.)

Comment: I live in Malaysia, so I cannot order from Arrow since the shipping would cost a lot, the part is really cheap, even after converted though. So I normally use element14 if I want a part urgently, and this is what I found, http://my.element14.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?storeId=10188&catalogId=15001&categoryName=&selectedCategoryId=&langId=83&categoryIdBox=&st=d44h11, for D44H11. RM3 for the part.

Comment: @JohnHJ I get it about element14. So about a dollar each, then, not counting shipping. Spendy. What can you get cheaply there which is designed for more than 5 A and comes in TO-220, at least?

Comment: I search, and I found D44H10 for RM1.6218 per piece. That is the cheapest I can find for BJT, carry at least 5A, and comes in TO-220.

Comment: @JohnHJ Perhaps about half the gain of the D44H11, from what little I can gather up quickly. But it is better than the first device you'd mentioned.

Comment: @JohnHJ You can invert the entire circuit, since the D44H10 is an NPN. Design it for a base current of about 200 mA, though. Can you do that?